# What is the type of a variable-length argument list in Scala?

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

Suppose that I declare a function as follows:

```
def test(args: String*) = args mkString
```

What is the type of `args`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is called a variable number of arguments or in short varargs. It's static type is `Seq[T]` where `T` represents `T*`. Because `Seq[T]` is an interface it can't be used as an implementation, which is in this case [`scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray). To find out such things it can be useful to use the REPL:

```
// static type
scala> def test(args: String*) = args
test: (args: String*)Seq[String]

// runtime type
scala> def test(args: String*) = args.getClass.getName
test: (args: String*)String

scala> test("")
res2: String = scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef
```

Varargs are often used in combination with the `_*` symbol, which is a hint to the compiler to pass the elements of a `Seq[T]` to a function instead of the sequence itself:

```
scala> def test[T](seq: T*) = seq
test: [T](seq: T*)Seq[T]

// result contains the sequence
scala> test(Seq(1,2,3))
res3: Seq[Seq[Int]] = WrappedArray(List(1, 2, 3))

// result contains elements of the sequence
scala> test(Seq(1,2,3): _*)
res4: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Yes, this has and interesting effect that you cannot pass the var-len args immediately, `def f1(args: Int*) = args.length; def f2(args: Int*) = f1(args)`. It will give `found Seq[Int] whereas Int is required mismatch error` in f2 definition. To circumvent, you need to `def f2 = f1(args: _*)`. So, compiler thinks that argument is a single value and sequence at the same, at compile time :)

Comment: As of Scala `2.13.6`, the implementation of `Seq` used is `scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq`.