# Break array and pass as arguments in scala

Tags: function, scala, arguments

I am new to scala so forgive me if this is easy to do.

I have an array consisting of values that I need to pass to a 
function. But the function accepts multiple arguments. The arguments are present but how do I break the array and pass it to the function?

In short I have array `[1,2,3]` and I want to call `func(1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. For `def func(a: Int*)` it can be done with:

```
func(arr:_*)
```

Comment: If anyone has a better way please add it. Any reason for downvoting ?

Comment: because it should be `func(arr: _*)`. Of course if `func` is defined as `def func(xs: Int*) = ???`. It won't apply if `func` is is defined as `def func(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = ???`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `apply` to get element by index:

```
val a = Array(1,2,3)
func(a(0), a(1), a(2))
```

or other way:

```
val Array(a,b,c,_) = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
func(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your function takes [*varargs* (such as `Int*`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205012/what-is-the-type-of-a-variable-length-argument-list-in-scala), then the solution in your reply works; however, if it actually takes multiple arguments, it doesn't. In this case you need to do `func(arr(0), arr(1), arr(2))` or use reflection:

```
// assumes func has exactly one apply method, modify to taste
val method = func.getClass.getMethods.filter(_.getName == "apply").head
method.invoke(func, arr)
```