# scala - Array("one", "two").mkString(":") defined in a method return WrappedArray, not a String

Tags: scala, methods

```
scala>   def joinWith(separator: String, values: String*): String = {
     |     Array(values).mkString(separator)
     |   }
joinWith: (separator: String, values: String*)String

scala> joinWith(":", "one", "two")
res0: String = WrappedArray(one, two)   // shouldn't we get a String here?

scala> Array("one", "two").mkString(":")
res1: String = one:two                  // this works as expected but only like this

scala>
```

I expected a `String` returned, but I see a `WrappedArray`. Why?

How should the function be defined, if I want a String returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the type of a variable-length argument list in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205012/what-is-the-type-of-a-variable-length-argument-list-in-scala)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only problem I see with your `joinWith` function is the way you convert variable arguments to an array. Result of `Array(values)` has a type `Array[Seq[String]]` - I doubt this is what you want. This is not necessary at all. The arguments `values` are already passed as `Seq` to you. Did you perhaps intend to write `values.mkString(separator)`?

The `WrappedArray` text you see is the result of `mkString` converting the inner `Array` with a value of `Array("one", "two")`to a string. You are not getting a value with a type `WrappedArray` (this would not even be possible, as you have explicitly typed your function to return a `String)`, you get a string with a value `WrappedArray(...)`

Comment: Yes I wanted to just join the content of the array, not wrap the content with another array and join. That is. New to Scala. Thanks.

Comment: I would argue that defining `joinWith` this way is not worth the effort. Do you really prefer `joinWith(":", "one", "two")` over `Seq("one", "two").mkString(":")`? It is your choice however, perhaps you have reasons to have it that way.

Comment: Oh just new so don't know any differences. Was searching but if you can shed some light that is nice.

Comment: Oh just new so don't know any differences between `Seq` and `List`. Was searching but if you can shed some light that is nice.
And if you want to argue the method call is nothing easier than the real invocation of `mkString`, I define this to change the elements when adding them into the list; I add `dev`, `int`, `uat`, etc to the list in several places and I want to dynamically comment some lines(I add them in different lines) so I change the environment by (un)commenting lines instead of changing inline.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
def joinWith(separator: String, values: String*): String =
    Array(values:_*).mkString(separator)
```

Here is the REPL:

```
scala> def joinWith(separator: String, values: String*): String = Array(values:_*).mkString(separator)
joinWith: (separator: String, values: String*)String

scala> joinWith(":", "a", "s")
res7: String = a:s
```

I think the problem was that you need to specify the `_*` to the `Array`.

As Suma says, if you do not specify the `_*`, you have the type `Array[Seq[String]]` when you create the Array.